# Angular $http function scope inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, scope

I'm having a problem trying to use "this" with angular functions (specifically $http.get) inside a controller.

Example:

Javascript- (psuedo code)

```
...
.controller('testController')
{
   $http.get(data)
  {
     this.Stuff = data;
  }
}
...
```

HTML-

```
<div ng-controller='testController as test'>
{{test.Stuff}}
</div>
```

When trying to access test.Stuff in the html, it is empty.

I understand that there is a scope issue, but shouldn't I be able to access the controller's 'this' inside of the $http function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll notice that `this` inside of your success callback refers to `window` (the global object).  Your success callback is being called with `window` as the context because functions that are not members of other functions are invoked with the `window` object as the context for the function.  If you want `this` to refer to your controller instance you must bind that context to the function. You can use [angular.bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) to accomplish this.

```
.controller('testController')
{
   $http.get(data).success(angular.bind(this, function(data) {
     this.Stuff = data;
  }));
}
```

Comment: Did you test this?

1. you need to add data as the callback parameter
2. you need to add another closing parentheses
3. i couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
controller('testController')
{
   var self = this;

   $http.get(data)
  {
     self.Stuff = data;
  }
}
```

I typically use the scope like this:

```
.controller('testController', function($scope) {
{
   $http.get(data)
  {
     $scope.Stuff = data;
  }
})
```

Comment: I've already used both and know they both work. thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't really answer my question. I understand that 'this' changes insides $http, but I'm trying to understand why it would since $http's scope should be inside the outer controller scope.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside the $http callback to see what `this` references.  I bet it references the $http service or window and not the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the data to your scope in the http callback like so:

```
app.controller('testController',function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        $scope.stuff = response;
    });
});
```